# Pdf encryption in cakePdf using dompdf

Tags: pdf, encryption, dompdf

I have researched on how to create a pdf using cakepdf. I have been able to successfully generated the pdf and attached to an email using using ceeram/CakePdf on GitHub. Now i want to encrypt the pdf sent by email. I have spent two days researching without any success. I tried the encryption tutorial on ceeram/CakePdf but it didn't work for me. I don't know what am doing wrong.

**In my bootstrape i have:**

```
CakePlugin::load('CakePdf', array('bootstrap' => true, 'routes' => true));
Configure::write('CakePdf', array(
        'engine' => 'CakePdf.DomPdf',
        'options' => array(
            'print-media-type' => false,
            'outline' => true,
            'dpi' => 96
        ),
        'margin' => array(
            'bottom' => 15,
            'left' => 50,
            'right' => 30,
            'top' => 45
        ),
        'paperSize' => 'A4',
        'orientation' => 'landscape',
        'download' => false,
    ));
    Configure::write('CakePdf.crypto', 'CakePdf.Pdftk');
```

**In my action, i have:**

```
$this->pdfConfig = array(
     'orientation' => 'portrait',
     'filename' => 'Invoice_'. 3,
     'options' => array(
            'protect' => true,
             'userPassword' => '123'
        ),
     'permissions'=>array('print','screen_readers','copy_contents')
 );

 $CakePdf = new CakePdf();
 $CakePdf->template('confirmpdf', 'default');
 //get the pdf string returned
 $pdf = $CakePdf->output();
 //or write it to file directly
 $pdf = $CakePdf->write(APP . 'webroot'. DS .'files' . DS . 'userdetail.pdf');
 $pdf = APP . 'webroot'. DS .'files' . DS . 'userdetail.pdf';
```

The pdf is generating fine as expected but its not been encrypted. What am i doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I guess the first question, do you have pdftk installed?

Comment: Have you tried the setEncryption() method of the CPDF library ([ref](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/dompdf-dev/IHnFkl7ejXw/wMFWFsNSStcJ))?

Comment: Thank you so much BrainS. I had to install pdftk and use php exec() function to get it working. Am now getting my encrypted pdf the way i want it. Once again thanks for your assistance.